# Unable to save data properly using foreach in php

Tags: php, laravel, multidimensional-array, dynamic-arrays

I am passing the `$data` as a parameter to a setter function in my model. `var_dump($data)` gives

```
array(2) {
  ["iconUrl"]=>
  string(31) "C:\fakepath\photo-125301449.jpg"
  ["title"]=>
  string(8) "Example1"
}
array(2) {
  ["iconUrl"]=>
  string(30) "C:\fakepath\photo-71823413.jpg"
  ["title"]=>
  string(12) "Example2"
}
```

I then do a `foreach` inside the setter function

```
foreach($data as $val) {
    $this->goalLink = [
        'iconUrl' => $val['iconUrl'],
        'title' => $val['title']
    ];
}
```

The constructor is defined like this

```
protected $goalLink = [];
public function __construct() {
    $this->goalLink = [
        [
            'iconUrl' => null,
            'title' => null
        ]
    ];   
}
```

Then there is finally a `createNew()` which sends data to my API

```
$client = API::client();
$url = API::url('exampleURL');
$data = [
    'goalLink' => [
        'iconUrl' => $this->goalLink['iconUrl'],
        'title' => $this->goalLink['title']
    ]
];
$response = $client->post($url, ['json' => $data]);
```

Now the problem is the data in not getting saved properly only data from the 2nd array is getting saved. Somewhere the the data is getting overwritten.

This is the response i am getting from the API

```
goalLink":[{"iconUrl":"C:\\fakepath\\photo-71823413.jpg","title":"Example2"}]
```

but it should have actually saved like this

```
goaloalLink":[{"iconUrl":"C:\fakepath\photo-125301449.jpg","title":"Example1"}, {"iconUrl":"C:\\fakepath\\photo-71823413.jpg","title":"Example2"}]
```

Comment: You are overwriting the complete value of `$this->goalLink` instead of appending to the array.

Comment: So what would be the right way to append the data into the array ?

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying . In other words, `$this->goalLink[] = $something` ; it seems you are missing the square brackets there.